# Automatically show a number of CSAT returns for me to hit 90% or above

Tags: excel, tracker

I have a Customer Satisfaction Tracker.
Our passing rate for CSAT is 90% and above.

I wanted to know how this tracker will give me a number of CSAT survey so that I can
make my VSAT score to 90 %..
Currently my VSAT score is only 85.11%.  I want to be able to know how many Very Satisfied and Satisfied returns do I have to make this into 90 %.

I want the figure to be shown in cell B7.

```
H3 = =(A3+B3)/F3
I3 = =D3/F3
J3 = =E3/F3
```

[image: csat tracker photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the formula in B7,

`=(F3*90-((A3+B3)*100))/10`

This just reverses the equation for 90% and finds the number of very satisfied and satisfied returns. Hope this helps.